# How does GetCharacterPlacement of WINAPI work?

Tags: c, winapi

I have stumbled across this function: [GetCharacterPlacement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getcharacterplacementa?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

It seems to me that this function can calculate coordinates of characters inside a string, so where a caret would be positioned. I have tried putting in the `GCP_RESULTS` struct and just look at the results with different flags, but I always got results that didn't satisfy me.

```
RECT r;
GetWindowRect(hWnd, &r);

string text = "Iam text\nNew line\nANother one";
size_t textLen = strlen(text);
GCP_RESULTS gcp_res;
ZeroMemory(&gcp_res, sizeof(GCP_RESULTS));
gcp_res.lStructSize = sizeof(GCP_RESULTS);
gcp_res.lpCaretPos = malloc(sizeof(int) * textLen);
gcp_res.lpOrder = malloc(sizeof(UINT) * textLen);
gcp_res.lpDx = malloc(sizeof(int) * textLen);
gcp_res.lpGlyphs = text;
gcp_res.nGlyphs = textLen;
gcp_res.lpOutString = malloc(textLen);

printf("RES: %d\n", GetCharacterPlacement(hdc, text, textLen, r.right - r.left, &gcp_res, GCP_GLYPHSHAPE | GCP_MAXEXTENT | GCP_DISPLAYZWG | GCP_CLASSIN | GCP_JUSTIFY | GCP_USEKERNING));
printf("INTS: %d, %d\n", gcp_res.nMaxFit, gcp_res.nGlyphs);
printf("OUT STR: %s\n", gcp_res.lpOutString);
printf("CLASS: %s\n", gcp_res.lpClass);
printf("LP GLYPHS: %s\n", gcp_res.lpGlyphs);
for(int i = 0; i < textLen; i++)
    printf("POINTERS: %d, %d, %d\n", *(gcp_res.lpCaretPos + i), *(gcp_res.lpDx+i), *(gcp_res.lpOrder + i));
```

Output:

```
RES: 0
INTS: 0, 29
OUT STR: ª9♀
CLASS: (null)
LP GLYPHS: Iam text
New line
ANother one
POINTERS: 2949464, 2949464, 2949464
POINTERS: 0, 0, 0
POINTERS: 2949464, 2949464, 2949464
POINTERS: 0, 0, 0
POINTERS: 0, 0, 0
         .
         .
         .
```

I expected the int arrays to have char widths or any of that kind, but I just got zeros. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's been awhile since I used GCP but I seem to recall that the default font selected into an HDC was insufficient, that I had to create an HFONT myself before it would work.

Comment: And the fact that your GCP call results in 0 means that the rest of the data is meaningless.